# Run Jenkins Pipelines jobs in parallel from closure

Tags: jenkins, groovy, closures, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins server using the Pipeline plugin. In this, I want to launch several builds in parallel, and wait for the builds to complete before moving on to the next stage of my pipeline.

I am able to do this successfully, if I write out the build jobs explicitly, like so:

```
parallel 'one': {
    build job: 'job1', 
        parameters: [
            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'CONFIG', value: "foo"]
        ],
        propagate: false,
        wait: true
},  'two': {
    build job: 'job2', 
        parameters: [
            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'CONFIG', value: "foo"]
        ],
        propagate: false,
        wait: true
},  'three': {
    build job: 'job3', 
        parameters: [
            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'CONFIG', value: "foo"]
        ],
        propagate: false,
        wait: true
}
```

However, in reality, there will be a variable number of jobs that need to be built, so explicitly writing these out is not feasible. I have tried to wrap the builds in a closure like so:

```
def createParallel = { String parallelName ->
    parallelName: {
        build job: 'jobX', 
            parameters: [
                [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'CONFIG', value: "foo"]
            ],
            propagate: false,
            wait: true
    }
}

parallel (
    createParallel('one'), 
    createParallel('two'), 
    createParallel('three')
)
```

The problem with this method is the builds do not actually kick off in parallel - They build one at a time, waiting for the previous build to complete. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying any build parameters, so Jenkins coalesces the queue items, by design.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I had removed them from this example to make it more readable. The real version does have parameters. Still, I don't really understand why the two versions would produce different results. Shouldn't they both coalesce without parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Set wait: false and build never wait for another build.But if you need to trigger another stage ,you have to get the result

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that presently this cannot be done in Jenkins, due to bugs [JENKINS-33051](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33051) and [JENKINS-25979](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25979).

What I was doing with the above was essentially creating three parallels, each with a single parameter. What needs to be done is place the closures in a list, and then spread the list as parameters, like so:

```
def list = [ createParallel('one'), createParallel('two'),  createParallel('three') ]
parallel (*list)
```

Unfortunately, this is not implemented in Jenkins right now.

Comment: `parallel` takes a map, not a list.  you can do this by constructing a map, either manually or via `inject`, and then passing that to `parallel`